# Python Scaling during GridSearchCV

Tags: python, keras, scaling

I have a question regarding preprocessing data for `GridSearchCV`, mainly pertaining to scaling.

So what I hope to achieve is:

Perform scaling (e.g. `StandardScaler()`) on training data during `GridSearchCV`, and not on the entire set which consists of both training data and testing data.

If I use a `Pipeline`, for example:

```
clf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GridSearchCV(KerasRegressor(), param_grid = [....], cv=10, refit=True))
```

I do not get the ability to choose whether the `StandardScaler()` is applied on the training set only during each fold -> I believe the scaling is done for the entire set for each fold.

Could I seek your advice please?

Thank you.

Comment: It should. But it won't hurt to run step by step experiment and pipeline experiment and compare the result. It will definitely answers your curiosity.  I love to see the results. :)

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#pipeline you can check this out if you want for details.

Comment: Thanks @BoyInDaBox89. Well it says: "Safety
    Pipelines help avoid leaking statistics from your test data into the trained model in cross-validation, by ensuring that the same samples are used to train the transformers and predictors." I'll just go ahead and assume that data snooping does not occur by doing this.

Comment: Sounds great!!!